# Oauth in spring web mvc project

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth

I need to add oauth security to spring mvc project.

The project have basic security that implement org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
with CustomAuthenticationProvider and i need to replace it with oauth2 .

is there a simple way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to protect resources with OAuth in Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431359/trying-to-protect-resources-with-oauth-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: the project contain only rest services that work with db so i didnt
understand exactly i need to implement when the user detail are in the db .

Answer (score 0):

We have done the same in one of our applications using Spring 4 and Java 8. The application is open source and you can read about the security layer here https://techdev.io/en/developer-blog/using-spring-and-oauth-in-trackr